# Increment the time by 15 mins in Java

Tags: java, time

I am able to get the time in format of `2020-02-10T11:30:00.000` as a start_time and end_time as `2020-02-10T11:45:00.000` as increment of 15 mins, now i want assign end_time into start_time, as well as end_time need to increase by 15 mins. This is where i am getting difficulty.

below is my code,

```java
public class DateUtil {

    final static String PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd" +"\'T\'" +"HH:mm:00.000";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = null;

    DateFarmatorDemo dateFarmatorDemo = new DateFarmatorDemo();
    DateFormat dateFormat = null;

    static String start_date = null;
    static String end_date = null;
    static String temp_date = null;

    public void requiredDate() {    

         Calendar start_date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
         start_date1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);

         Calendar end_date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
         end_date1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
         end_date1.add(Calendar.MINUTE, +15);

         dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(PATTERN);
         start_date= dateFormat.format(start_date1.getTime());
         end_date= dateFormat.format(end_date1.getTime());

         for(int i=0; i <=10 ; i++) {
        //end_date= dateFormat.format(start_date1.getTime());
        //increment by 15 mins to end_date

                dateFarmatorDemo.setStart_Date(start_date);
                System.out.println("Start Date ->  "+ dateFarmatorDemo.getStart_Date());

                dateFarmatorDemo.setEnd_Date(end_date);
                System.out.println("End Date ->  " + dateFarmatorDemo.getEnd_Date());

                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
         }  
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please include the code where your difficulty is

Comment: Which Java versions do you have available? The answers might differ significantly between Java 7 or less and 8+ (`Date` vs `Instant`)

Answer (score 2):

You are using terrible legacy classes. Use only *java.time* classes instead.

Your Question is not clear as to your exact goal. But this should get you close.

Capture the current moment is seen in a particular time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Add your 15 minutes.

```
ZonedDateTime later = zdt.plusMinutes( 15 ) ;
```

If parsing input strings in standard ISO 8601 format but lacking time zone or offset, parse as `LocalDateTime` objects.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2020-01-23T15:30:00" );
```

Assign the time zone intended for that input, to determine a moment, a point on the timeline.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8+ you can use **java.time** package.
If you date-time does not depend of *Time Zone* you can use **LocalDateTime**-class:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
LocalDateTime start_date = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-02-10T11:30:00.000", dtf)
LocalDateTime end_date = LocalDateTime.of(2020,02,10,11,45,0,0);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    start_date = start_date.plusMinutes(15);
    end_date = end_date.plusMinutes(15);
    System.out.println("Start Date ->  " + start_date);
    System.out.println("End Date   ->  " + end_date);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
}
```